# Assigning HTML returned via ajax to any HTML element value

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have trying to assign the html returned from ajax to the value of any html element. The html returned only contains 22.5. So I want to assign this value to any html element value.

The code I am using is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#coupon_btn").click(function(){
        //alert("hello");
        var coupon=$("#coupon").val();
        var mem_price=$("#mem_price").val();
        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'http://localhost/freakinout1/paypal/coupon.php',
           data: "coupon="+coupon+"&price="+mem_price,
           cache: false,
           success: function(html) {
                var pay = $("#Payment_Amount").val();
                $("#Payment_Amount").val() = html;
                alert(pay);
               //$('#search-results-container').html(html);
           }
        });
    });
});
```

The error I am getting in error console is invalid assignment left hand side.

So could someone suggest me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `val()` function accepts a parameter to set the `value` of the object on which it is called, pass `html` variable to `val()` Note val() is used with html elements of input type like text, checkbox etc. If Payment_Amount is div or span then you will need to use `html()` or `text()`.

*Change*

```
$("#Payment_Amount").val() = html;
```

*To*

```
$("#Payment_Amount").val( html);
```

Answer (score 0):

for setting a value you need to pass string in [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2)..

try this

```
$("#Payment_Amount").val() = html;
```

replace with

```
$("#Payment_Amount").val(html);
                    //---^^^^ here
```